# Configure Consul Watches with HTTP Endpoint Handler through CLI

Tags: consul, spring-cloud-consul, consul-kv, consul-health-check

I am starting out with Consul, and I was wondering if there is a way to set the HTTP handler configuration(s) (i.e. `path`, `method`, etc.) through the CLI command itself (`consul watch`), *without using a configuration file* (with `-config-file` argument).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to defining Consul watches in the agent configuration, you can directly execute watches using the [`consul watch`](https://www.consul.io/commands/watch) CLI. For example,

```sh
$ consul watch -type=key -key=foo/bar/baz /usr/bin/my-key-handler.sh
```

Additional examples of defining watches either in the agent config, or the CLI, can be found at https://www.consul.io/docs/dynamic-app-config/watches.

The CLI, however, only supports executing script handlers. It is not possible to configure the `consul watch` CLI to use an HTTP handler. HTTP handlers can only be used when watches are defined in the agent configuration.